# Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

На "Грамоте.ру" написано: "Оборот не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу". (Как правило, в таких случаях оборот нельзя изъять из состава предложения, не исказив при этом смысл фразы.) Например:

...Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат ***с согласия отца*** украл у него лошадь... М. Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени. (смысл у Лермонтова: Казбич вообразил, будто отец Азамата дал согласие на кражу.) Ср. изменение смысла при обособлении оборота: ...Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат, *с согласия отца,* украл у него лошадь... (=Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат украл лошадь.)

Как видно из примеров, в одном случае выделенный мной оборот выделяется запятыми, в другом — нет. И от этого, как указывает "Грамота.ру", меняется смысл.

Вопрос: в обоих примерах, независимо от запятой, остаётся предлог "с согласия". Какую тогда он играет роль при обособлении? Если смысл при обособлении такой: "Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат украл  лошадь". Почему тогда не убрать предлог? Он ведь здесь не информативен.
Какие соображения у вас, коллеги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: "Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь".

Лошадь украдена - это факт, похититель также установлен - это Азамат, значит, предположение можно строить только относительно согласия отца. Следовательно, логически выделяется именно это словосочетание и обособляться оно не может.

При обособлении "с согласия отца" в ударную позицию попадает "Азамат", то есть он становится  подозреваемым. Поэтому думать о согласии или несогласии  отца Казбичу не имеет смысла, пока он точно не уверен в своих подозрениях. Обособление оборота - это, скорее, не другой смысл, а просто семантическая неточность.

Когда же по тексту романа Казбич  узнает имя похитителя, то неясным становится только "согласие отца" (тогда обособление оборота невозможно, так как на него падает ударение).

Comment: София, последнее предложение я не очень понял. "....то неясным становится только "согласие отца" (тогда обособление оборота невозможно, так как на него падает ударение). Если не выделять оборот, то ясным будет как раз "согласие отца". На первый план выходит предлог "с согласия".

Comment: Я имела в виду, что единственный вопрос, ответ на который ищет Казбич, - это согласие отца, поэтому на него падает ударение и обособлять его нельзя.

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен. Но все же. Обособление, согласно Грамоте, допускается в этом примере, и смысл меняется.

Comment: (1)"Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь". Казбич знает, что это Азамат, и предполагает, что с согласия отца.(2)"Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат, с согласия отца, украл у него лошадь". Казбич только предполагает, что это Азамат.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и убрать, только не предлог, а всё предложное сочетание С СОГЛАСИЯ ОТЦА, но смысл тогда, действительно, меняется в корне. Нет запятых - Казбич чувствует враждебность отца Азамата, есть запятые при пояснительном обособленном обороте - вина на Азамате при молчаливом пособничестве отца.Нет всего оборота - Азамат один виновен, это шалость мальчишки, а не обида от его отца, не враждебность. Отношение совсем другое. Так что оборот без запятых  здесь необходим, чтобы потом показать, что горец Казбич жестоко мстит за нанесённую обиду, он убивает отца Азамата, а мы чувствуем в словах автора, знающего обычаи гор и уважающего их, что он в чём-то даже симпатизирует ему, наказавшему обидчика.

Comment: То, что оборот без запятых необходим, - это ясно. С запятыми получается, что вина на Азамате, без запятых - на отце? Я правильно вас понял, Людмила?

Comment: Да, без запятых на отце, с запятыми - участие отца есть, но косвенное, оно не может вызвать жестокой мести.

Comment: Моральная сторона вопроса к обособлению не имеет прямого отношения. Смысловая разница, которую усматривает Грамота.ру, заключается в СТЕПЕНИ ИНФОРМИРОВАННОСТИ Казбича. В первом случае (без обособления)он точно ЗНАЕТ, что это Азамат украл лошадь (что соответствует тексту романа), а во втором случае (с обособлением) только ПРЕДПОЛАГАЕТ это.

Comment: Да, скорее всего вы правы, София. Во втором случае он лишь предполагает, что Казбич украл лошадь с согласия отца, поэтому предложное сочетание остается, но уже отходит на второй план.

Answer (score 0):

***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

Если оборот с согласия отца будет обособлен, он будет играть роль попутного замечания. Смысл будет таким: Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат украл лошадь, да еще и с согласия отца.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что Справка несколько переоценила значение обособления.
Т.е. его, обособления, свойство дифференцировать смысл.

Тут без контекста вообще сложно сказать, относилось ли "согласие отца" к краже лошади или к воображаемой части.  И никакое обособление этого не изменит.
Вот если знать нверняка, что лошадь украдена Азаматом - и этот факт доподлинно известен Казбичу (кажется, по тексту оно так и есть), то мысль "Справки" становится понятной (хотя и не бесспорной). По её мнению, обособление оборота означало бы что Казбич вообразил, что лошадь украдена Азаматом (а он это, как мы приняли, и так наверняка знает), а отец упомянут вскользь. А вот без обособления весь смысл того, что Казбич вообразил, переносится именно на согласия отца.  Как-то так... Не на все 100, но в общем-то можно согласиться.

Логика у них такая.
Если оборот обособлен, то он может быть изъят без существенного изменения смысл. А поскольку после изъятия весь смысл ложится на Азамата,то и с обособленным оборотом должно быть также. Тут все правильно, придраться трудно...
А вот почему в случае необособленного оборота смысл *однозначно* переходит на отца, не совсем понятно... Вернее понятно только по контексту. Логика типа "иначе бы обособили" (читай: "обособление выполняет смыслоразличительную функцию") тут как-то не срабатывает. Причинно-следственная связь нарушается. 
Да и реально не подтверждается: фразу (в лермонтовской пунктуации, но без контекста) вполне можно понять и так, что Казбич вообразил сразу две вещи: что Азамат лошадь украл и что сделал это с согласия отца. А еще есть вариант, что украли-то с согласия отца, но не Азамат, а вот Казбич вообразил, что именно Азамат. И это не все, тут куча вариантов для гадания на кофейной гуще.

Для однозначного восприятия не хватает какой малости, Может, междометия какого-то или усилительной частицы...

*Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат **это** с согласия отца украл у него лошадь.*
*Казбич вообразил, будто **это** Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь.*

Вроде бы сорное словечко, а все ставит на свои места. А заодно и иллюстрирует неоднозначность понимания понимания "по Справке". Обособления "согласия" не требуется вопреки справкиной логике...

Простите за длинноты, тут тонкая для меня материя, кратко не умею.

Comment: @behemothus,в предложении "...Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь...",как утверждает справка,("смысл у Лермонтова: Казбич вообразил, будто отец Азамата дал согласие на кражу".) Они не утверждают, что если оборот обособлен, то он может быть изъят без существенного изменения смысл. Подробнее здесь:[ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ1 ПРЕДЛОГАМИ](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/)